# How to switch between pages in JSOUP, if pagination jquery

Tags: jsoup

There is a service that sends messages from the database. I want to import all clients, but the service doesn't provide such functionality. I thought that it is possible to do parsing with the help of jsoup, but pagination is implemented not in the url, but through jquery, how can I parse this data.

[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUjFC.png)

How can I switch pages?